# Why is my resx file generating System.Drawing.Icon for Upgraded NetStandard Project

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I modified an existing .net 461 project to use netstandard 2.0 by creating a new project file and switching the target framework to `netstandard20`

Everything seems to work except my resource files, which contain icons. I added the following to my csproj file to ensure the generation was run:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

However, every time the Designer.cs file gets generated it has references to `System.Drawing.Icon` which is not valid for a .Net Standard Project. How can I configure the designer file to correctly use `System.Byte[]` for my icon resources?

Comment: Use .netstandard only for library projects and only for code that has some hope to be cross-platform compatible.  Neither icons nor System.Windows.Forms are.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree completely.  I am trying to incrementally move pieces from net461 to netstandard. I ran into this issue when migrating an assembly and thought I would share to help others in case they ran into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Resource.resx` file has the type name to use for generation embedded in the XML. You need to modify this file with a text editor and direct it to use `System.byte[]` instead of `System.Drawing.Icon`.

For example, you may have the following entry in your resource.resx file:

```
<data name="FooBar" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>..\Resources\FooBar.ico;System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
</data>
```

You can update the output type to be a byte array like so:

```
<data name="FooBar" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>..\Resources\FooBar.ico;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</data>
```

Comment: note that this only works from "full msbuild" (VS or mono). The .NET Core based tooling (`dotnet build`) only supports strings in resx

Comment: @MartinUllrich Is that just a tooling issue? As long as the net standard binaries contain the full resources, then consumers of the library should be able to use them, correct?

Comment: just a tooling issue, .net core msbuid only has a naive xml parser to generate string pairs from the data/@name data/value pairs, full framework msbuild use the data/@type type to serialize the data. just wanting to point this out for info.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I've just experienced this myself, so how can I "imitate" VS from the command line? I've tried dotnet msbuild but it isn't generating resources differently...

Comment: use `msbuild` from the developer command prompt, e.g. `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release`

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that too, but while that solves the resource problem indeed, I'm left unable to control the runtime-identifier (x64/x86) and resulting nuget references (for example Microsoft.Data.Sqlite)...